# How to locate 2 text with same xpath?

Tags: python, robotframework

How to locate text within same xpath?
I used but not work:

```
//div[contains(text(),"Review") and contains(text(),"received"]
```

[image]

Comment: You are missig the close ')' --> //div[contains(text(),"Review") and contains(text(),"received")]

Answer (score 0):

The texts belong to two different tags. You can look for element with `"Review"` text which has a child with `"received"` text

```
//div[contains(text(),"Review") and div[contains(text(),"received")]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Take care, you are mission the closer ')'

```
//div[contains(text(),"Review") and contains(text(),"received")]
```

But this is not the good xpath, cause "received" is on inner element

Try this, .//* means any child element, can use ./div on second contains

```
//div[.//*[contains(text(),"Review")] and .//*[contains(text(),"received")]]
```

or

```
//div[contains(text(),"Review") and .//*[contains(text(),"received")]]
```